# INSERT INTO Table WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, where-clause

I am working with Postgres and Python (psycopg2).

I am looking for a way to INSERT data into a table.

Assuming a table with 10 rows. id going from 1 to 10. Taking a row (i.e id = 3) with a WHERE condition, all my columns are filled with some value, except 2 columns (col3 and col4). Meaning col1,col2 and col5 have values in it. col3 and col4 have NULL conditions, explaining why they are empty in the first place.

I would like to fill these 2 columns with some Data.

I am looking for something like:

```
INSERT INTO table_a (col3,col4) WHERE id = 3 VALUES ...
```

Bottom line, I would like to find the row I should fill my two empty columns with the Data I would like.

Comment: look up the `UPDATE <tablename> SET <columnnname>=<value> WHERE id = xyz` syntax

Comment: INSERT in combination with WHERE makes no sense whatsoever - INSERT creates a _new_ record. You want to _UPDATE_ existing records.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for an `update` statement, not an `insert` statement:

```
UPDATE table_a
SET    col3 = 'some_value', col4 = 'some_other_value
WHERE  id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE table_a 
    SET col3 = ?,
        col4 = ?
    WHERE id = 3;
```

`INSERT` inserts new rows into a table.  `UPDATE` updates existing rows.

Answer (score 0):

If the row already exist,  you are looking for an update rather than an insert.

```
UPDATE table
   SET col3 = valueY, 
       col4 = valueX
 WHERE id = 3
```

Does this make sense to you?